# Asterisk hangup-handler

Tags: queue, asterisk, survey

I am new to Asterisk.
I am trying to define a hangup-handler for a survey.
The survey needs to be activated after the agent hangs up the call.

I put that to my [macro-queue] context,

`exten => s,n,ExecIf($["${HASH(queueInfo,survey)}" != "1" & "${isfinishcall}" !="1"] ?Set(CHANNEL(hangup_handler_push)=goto-anket,s,1(${HASH(queueInfo,survey)})))`

and I defined that for survey,

`[goto-anket] exten => s,1,Noop(Ankete Geldi) exten => s,2,Agi(anket.php) exten => s,3,Return()`

but when the agent hangs up the call is not activated. What should I do?

Comment: When the agent hangups the call shouldn't go to hangup and I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: Maybe you should debug it? I bet your first line never go.

Comment: Anyway, it is offtopic on SO(any debug).

Answer (score -1):

its not worked.  because change is closed
you need to do that via queue with option 'C'
example
exten => 1000,n(qcall),Queue(1000,tc,,${QAANNOUNCE},${QMAXWAIT},${QAGI},,${QGOSUB},${QRULE},${QPOSITION})